# Unable to send multiple sms on selected contact in table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a problem with my function when i try to send multiple sms based on selected contacts in the table of my admin panel when i click send button, it only send one sms. By the way i am using laravel and vuejs and axios.

Here's is my function in my controller:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request, $id){

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Japan');
    $secret = $request->input('secret');
    $deviceID = $request->input('deviceID');
    $time = time();
    $secretMd5 = md5($secret.$time);

    $single_user_id = explode(',' , $id);           
    foreach ($single_user_id as $id) {   
       $number = Contact::find($id)->where('id', $id)->value('mobile_number');
       $message = $request->input('message'); 
    }
    return file_get_contents("https://"server"/?to=".urlencode(trim($number))."&text=".urlencode($message)."&secret=$secretMd5&time=$time&deviceID=".$deviceID);
}
```

Here is my route in api.php

```
Route::post('send/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@sendMessage');
```

Here is my method in vue.js:

```
        Send(selected) {
            const vm = this;
            axios.post("/api/send/" + selected, this.sms)
                .then(response => {
                    vm.getContact();
                        this.select_all = false;
                        this.selected = [];
                        this.sms.secret = null;
                        this.sms.deviceID = null;
                        this.sms.message = null;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        },
```

Comment: Just put `file_get_contents(...)` code block inside foreach and make sure `single_user_id ` array has multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your controller method

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Japan');
    $secret = $request->input('secret');
    $deviceID = $request->input('deviceID');
    $time = time();
    $secretMd5 = md5($secret.$time);

    $single_user_id = $request->input('ids);           
    foreach ($single_user_id as $id) {   
       $number = Contact::where('id', $id)->pluck('mobile_number');
       $message = $request->input('message'); 
       file_get_contents("https://"server"/?to=".urlencode(trim($number))."&text=".urlencode($message)."&secret=$secretMd5&time=$time&deviceID=".$deviceID);
    }
    return response()->json(); // If you want json response
    
}
```

If you want more clear code then you can use :

```
Route::post('send-sms', 'App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@sendMessage');
```

and in vue :

```
        Send(selected) {
            const vm = this;
            this.sms.ids = selected;
            axios.post("/api/send-sms", this.sms)
                .then(response => {
                    vm.getContact();
                        this.select_all = false;
                        this.selected = [];
                        this.sms.secret = null;
                        this.sms.deviceID = null;
                        this.sms.message = null;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        },
```